# Boxes of different sizes in a matrix

Tags: matrices

I wish to represent the CKM matrix

```
\[
V=\begin{pmatrix} 
  0.974 & 0.225 & 0.003 \\ 
  0.225 & 0.973 & 0.041 \\
  0.009 & 0.040 & 0.999 
\end{pmatrix}
\]
```

visually. That is, insert correct sized boxes instead of numbers. Something like this.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried to do yourself?

Comment: You could use, e.g., `\fcolorbox` (needs [package `xcolor`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) or [`color`](https://ctan.org/pkg/color)) or a [TikZ](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) `matrix`. BTW: You should not use `$$…$$` in LaTeX. Use either `\[…\]` or `\begin{displaymath}…\end{displaymath}` or one of the [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) environments for displayed math.

Comment: What is the correlation of value to box size? How is the color determined?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Colour is irrelevant, box sizes are meant to represent "similarly sized arguments" - show that the matrix is almost diagonal

Comment: @cabohah Can I specify size of an individual box with this package? Size is an issue I would like to modify - show that diagonal elements dominate. Colour itself is irrelevant.

Comment: @Zarko I have tried colorbox, but I can only vary colour, not size. Size is a primary variable in my problem - I wish to show that diagonal elements dominate in a nice, visual way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\ColorBox` macro has

- one optional argument (default `black`) for the border color,
- one mandatory argument for the background color (i.e. your main color) and
- one mandatory argment that determines the size.

It uses:

- `\makebox[2em][c]{…}` to have every square in a cell to be horizontally centered in the space of `2em`,
- The `\fboxsep` length is adjusted so that every box doesn't add any padding.
- The `\raisebox` makes sure the squared are vertically centered.
- The main attraction: `\fcolorbox{<border>}{<background>}{<text>}`

  Here `<border>` is the border color (`#1` from `\ColorBox`), `<background>` is the background color (`#2`) and `<text>` is the actual content which is …
- … two rules (lines), one is vertical, the other one is horizontal. But they don't have any thickness (notice the `0pt`) which means they just occupy space but don't show up.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*\ColorBox[3][black]{%
  \makebox[2em][c]{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{-.5\fboxrule}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr-#3em+.5ex}{%
      \fcolorbox{#1}{#2}{%
        \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr#3em*2}%
        \rule{\dimexpr#3em*2}{0pt}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{r ccc @{\qquad} r ccc}
  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\text{CKM}} & & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\text{PNMS}} \\
  & d & s & b & & v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
u & \ColorBox{yellow}{.974}
  & \ColorBox{blue}{.225}
  & \ColorBox{red}{.003} 
  & v_e
  & \ColorBox{yellow!90!black}{.8}
  & \ColorBox{blue}{.65}
  & \ColorBox{red}{.2} \\
c & 
  & \ColorBox{yellow}{.974}
  & 
  & v_\mu
  & \ColorBox{green}{.5}
  & \ColorBox{blue}{.65}
  & \ColorBox{yellow}{.9} \\
t & 
  & 
  & \ColorBox{yellow}{.974}
  & v_\tau
  & \ColorBox{green}{.5}
  & \ColorBox{blue}{.65}
  & \ColorBox{yellow}{.9} \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks man! This is beyond perfect - it helps me so much!

Answer (score 5):

The answer based on `tikz`.

Here's example macro `\rect[scale]{colour}` which draws images using `tikz`. It contains two simple commands: one that draws invisible square to ensure size of the image, currently 1.15cm, and the other which draws a colourful square. You can decide how large the square should be by providing a scale e.g. `1.0` (default) which draws a square of size of `1cm`. The whole image can be scaled with an optional parameter in `tikzpicture`, also called `scale`--it is different and independent to `scale` parameter the macro is using. The default value is `1.0` but `1.25` also gives a good result.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{lightyellow}{green!5!yellow!80}
\colorlet{darkyellow}{red!10!yellow}

\NewDocumentCommand\rect{O{1}m}{%
    \def\padding{1.15}%  % 1.15 cm invisible box size
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            scale=1.0,
            inner sep=0pt,
            outer sep=0cm,
            baseline={([yshift=-.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        ]
        \path
            (-\padding/2,-\padding/2)
            rectangle
            (\padding/2,\padding/2);
        \draw [line width=0.8pt, fill=#2]
            (-#1/2,-#1/2)
            rectangle
            (#1/2, #1/2);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}


\begin{document}
\section*{What is the origin of Quark and Lepton Mixing?}

\begin{table}[tbh]
    \centering
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \begin{tabular}{c @{\;} *{3}{c}}
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{CMK} \\
        & \textbf{d}
        & \textbf{s}
        & \textbf{b} \\
        \textbf{u}
        & \rect{lightyellow}
        & \rect[0.4]{blue}
        & \rect[0.05]{green} \\
        \textbf{c}
        & \rect[0.4]{green}
        & \rect{lightyellow} 
        & \rect[0.15]{green} \\
        \textbf{t}
        & \rect[0.05]{cyan}
        & \rect[0.15]{blue}
        & \rect{lightyellow}
    \end{tabular}%
    \hspace{4em}%
    \begin{tabular}{c @{\;} *{3}{c}}
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{PMNS} \\
        & $\boldsymbol{\nu_{1}}$
        & $\boldsymbol{\nu_{2}}$
        & $\boldsymbol{\nu_{3}}$ \\
        $\boldsymbol{\nu_{e}}$ 
        & \rect[0.85]{darkyellow}
        & \rect[0.55]{blue}
        & \rect[0.1]{red} \\
        $\boldsymbol{\nu_{\mu}}$ 
        & \rect[0.4]{green} 
        & \rect[0.55]{blue}
        & \rect[0.7]{lightyellow} \\
        $\boldsymbol{\nu_{\tau}}$
        & \rect[0.4]{green} 
        & \rect[0.55]{blue}
        & \rect[0.7]{lightyellow} \\
    \end{tabular}\qquad
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to you as well! But sadly, I need a form I can put in equation environment!

Comment: @displayname17: You can put a `tabular` inside an equation environment if you want; nothing prohibits you from doing that.

Comment: @Werner That is good to know, thanks!